# Qt and unicode escape string

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8, escaping

I'm getting from server data using signal and slot. Here is slot part:

```
QString text(this->reply->readAll());
```

Problem is, that in text variable will be unicode escape, for example:

```
\u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u044c\u0441\u044f ;-)
```

Is there any way to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
QString text = QString::fromUtf8(this->reply->readAll());
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8

Assuming it's Utf8, otherwise use [`fromUtf16`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf16)

Comment: I think OP means he's getting Unicode escape byte sequence. ie: '\','u','0','4','3','d' 6 bytes representing a 16-bit code point.

Comment: It works only if i write something like:
QString text = QString::fromUtf8("\u043d\u0435");
Maybe it's because in response from server can be not only escape, for example:
[{"recipient":{"favourites_count":1,"profile_text_color":"000000","url":null,"description":"\u0421\u0442\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0442 4-\u0433\u043e \u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0430 \u041c\u0418\u042d\u041c

Comment: Are you passing the entire `[{"recipient":{"favourites_count":1,"profile_text_color":"000000","url":null,"description":"\u0421\u0442\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0442 4-\u0433\u043e \u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0430 \u041c\u0418\u042d\u041c` in, or just the unicode part?  I think you will have to do some work to separate the sections first since its mixed formatting.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you needed:

(Find occurrences of \uCCCC using regex and replace them by the QChar with unicode number CCCC in base 16)

```
QRegExp rx("(\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})");
int pos = 0;
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    str.replace(pos++, 6, QChar(rx.cap(1).right(4).toUShort(0, 16)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this one??

```
QString text = reply->readAll().replace("\","\\");
```

By using the above snippet, you can replace the single slash to double slash, so that the single slash can be obtained as such. Hope it works.