# Detect and print Unicode characters with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to read and print a file that may or may not contain UTF-8 codes.

My example file contains:

hi
\u22a2
hey

My niave code:

```
    QFile file("/path/qteststream.txt");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ))
        std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;

    QTextStream stream(&file);
    QTextStream qout(stdout);
    stream.setAutoDetectUnicode(true);

    while(!stream.atEnd())
      qout << stream.readLine() << endl;
```

But obviously, Im doing something wrong. I'd expect \u22a2 to be printed as a unicode character, but the programm just prints the string. How can I make print such sequences as characters?

Comment: Do the input file literally contain the exact string "\u22a2"? Or did you use another program to write the actual character '\u22a2'? If it's the first, I doubt the QT stream classes will convert it automatically.

Comment: Yes, `\u22a2` is containg as a string. Should I convert it manually, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u22a2` may be interpreted as a Unicode character by your C++ compiler, but things are different outside source code. In a text file, `\u22a2` is merely 6 characters (`\`, `u`, `2`, `2`, `a`, and `2`) in succession. Try pasting `⊢` directly into the text file.

If you intentionally have `\u22a2` in the text file and want to convert it into a Unicode character, you may want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047000/1160310).

Comment: Well, actually I tried to spare the user the googling for tables and copy&pasting the characters. So, should I just look for strings starting with `\u` and convert them using `QString::fromUtf8()` ?

Comment: @EvgeniB.: Check the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `\u` escape codes are used in C/C++ files only, not in input files. "Unicode autodetection" means that the file can be UTF-8 (ASCII as a subset is also okay), or UCS-2 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and that will be transparent to your application.